# How to write audio filter drivers for xp

Tags: windows, driver, audio-streaming

I would like to write a filter driver for XP to intercept the audio and writing it into RDP virtual channel. How to do it? Where can I get the samples?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[GFX Filter Drivers on XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff536403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  May not be available on newer versions of the OS since XP.